# Grab Array Value and Label from an external JSON file and add it to a jQuery Autocomplete function

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am trying to add a jQuery UI Autocomplete to an input field. Similar to this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC"
];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

I followed the demo and that's easy to do. The hard part for me is to bring data from another json file called albums.json:

```
{
    "albums": [
        {
            "value": "Author Name",
            "label": "Album Name"
        },
        {
            "value": "Author Name",
            "label": "Album Name"
        },
        {
            "value": "Author Name",
            "label": "Album Name"
        },
        {
            "value": "Author Name",
            "label": "Album Name"
        },
    ]
}
```

Is it any easy way to do this? I have been trying to figure it out myself but I can't.

Thanks in advance, IL

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `ajax` to get data from external source as data for autocomplete. Try this.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
     $.ajax({
       url: "UrlOfThePage",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function( data ) {
         response(data.albums);
       }
     });
   }
});
```